# Trouble connecting to self-hosted IR from ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Self-hosted IR is installed on VM in Azure. Registered the IR, but the status is in "Running(limitted).
Error details:
Cloud service cannot connect to the integration runtime through service bus. You may not be able to use the Copy Wizard to create data pipelines for copying data from/to on-premises data stores. To resolve this, ensure there is no connectivity issues with Azure Relay. This requires enabling outbound communication to ‘*.servicebus.windows.net’ on Port ‘443’; either directly through this Integration Runtime or by using a Proxy Server. See Ports and security considerations and Proxy server considerations in the Integration runtime article for details. As a work-around in case Azure Relay connectivity cannot be established, code (or) Azure PowerShell to construct the pipelines (no UI authoring). Appreciate your help. Thank you

Appreciate your help resolving this issue. Thank you

Comment: Can you please make sure to whitelist the required services on the proxy server. 

if you whitelists only IP addresses, then you need to whitelist based on our documentation for service bus and Azure relay 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#ports-and-firewalls

if you can can whitelist FQDNs, pleasae see the follwing document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#get-url-of-azure-relay